# append a colored text to another text on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am developing an application in Cocoa.
I need to append a colored text to another text in table view, Is there a any way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it will let you do exactly this.